# Cluster Manager, cannot assign custom icon to MarkerOptions

Tags: google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-markers

I'm using the Google Maps Utils to group the markers. Now I want to customize the cluster icon and to do that I'm using this code

```
class ClusteredMarkerRender(context: Context, map: GoogleMap, clusterManager: ClusterManager<ClusteredMarker>)
    : DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusteredMarker>(context, map, clusterManager) {

    override fun onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster: Cluster<ClusteredMarker>?, markerOptions: MarkerOptions?) {
        super.onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster, markerOptions)

        markerOptions!!.icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.id.cluster_icon)
    }

    override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<ClusteredMarker>?): Boolean {
        return cluster!!.size > 1
    }
}
```

but on `markerOptions!!.icon` Android Studio says `val cannot be reassigned`. How am I supposed to assign my custom icon to the `markerOptions` instance?

Comment: You should call method markerOptions.icon(), not reassing value, I think.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem

Answer (score 2):

As said by asm0dey, the correct way to assign the icon was

```
markerOptions!!.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.id.cluster_icon))
```